# View array element by index in Watch in VS

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-debugging

Is it posible to watch element, by adding something to variable in index of an array in C++?

For example when I want to watch `i`-th element of array `A` in Watch Window (also in Immediate Window) i used `A[i]`, and everything is ok, but when I want to see `A[i+1]`, the value is wrong.

I found out, that memory adress of `&(A[i])` is correct and equal to `&A + i`, but `&(A[i+1])` is always the same as `&A`. I also found that even `&(A[1+1])` is also set to `&A`.

When I asking this question I realised that I can use `*(&A[i] + 1)`.

This is workaround. But still I have a question, is this some kind of problem with Visual Studio 2012, that user cannot add enything in array index in Watch Window?

Comment: I think that it's the standard behaviour of VS, but I'm not sure of it.

Answer (score 0):

That's an odd behavior indeed. :)

Another alternative is to use the following syntax to display the ith value and the following, slightly shorter but not ideal:

```
&a[i],2
```